# Scala groupBy+map issue

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

Live example here: [Scastie Example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pHj0e5P0SMWANNt1jfkubQ)

I don't understand how this works. I have a Seq of tuples like so:

```
val v = Seq(
  ("provider@test.com",2), 
  ("consumer@test.com",2), 
  ("provider@test.com",9), 
  ("provider@test.com",10)
)
```

I want to group them like so:

```
v.groupBy{ case(email, id) => id }
```

This results in:

```
Map(
  2 -> List(
      (provider@test.com,2),
      (consumer@test.com,2)
  ), 
  10 -> List(
      (provider@test.com,10)
  ), 
  9 -> List(
      (provider@test.com,9)
  )
)
```

Which makes perfect sense, but now if i map them again like so:

```
v.groupBy{ case(email, id) => id}.map{case(id, data) => data.head}.toSeq
```

I expect the result to be:

```
Vector((provider@test.com,2), (provider@test.com,10), (provider@test.com,9))
```

However I get:

```
Vector((provider@test.com,9))
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bit confusing. This happens because `map` on `Map[K, V]` also returns a `Map[K', V']` pair, and because your keys are all the same (the mailing address), you get back only a single value.

This can be avoided using `.values` which returns an `Iterable` of the values in the `Map`, and then `.map`:

```
v
 .groupBy { case (_, id) => id }
 .values
 .map(_.head)
 .toList
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you carelessly invoke `map` on a `Map`.
In this case, the pairs

```
  2 -> List(
      (provider@test.com,2),
      (consumer@test.com,2)
  ), 
  10 -> List(
      (provider@test.com,10)
  ), 
  9 -> List(
      (provider@test.com,9)
  )
```

are transformed into pairs

```
(provider@test.com,2)
(provider@test.com,10)
(provider@test.com,9)
```

and then again inserted into the freshly constructed map, overriding the value 2 by 10 then by 9. The final result is a map of type `Map[String, Int]` with a single entry `(provider@test.com,9)`, which is of course not what you wanted.

Do this instead:

```
println(v.groupBy{ case(email, id) => id}.toSeq.map{case(id, data) => data.head})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `groupBy` you get a `Map[Int, Seq[(String, Int)]]`. The `map` method will operate on each entry in your `Map[Int, Seq[(String, Int)]]`. If you just want to operate on the values you can do

```
v.groupBy{ case(email, id) => id}.mapValues(...
```

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You're right. That's what I meant to write. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

That was wrong because you invoked a map method on Map object as already pointed out by Andrey Tyukin. Convert it to list first and then apply map method with appropriate conversion function as below :
 **This works:**

```
 v.groupBy{ case(email, id) => id}.toList.map(_._2.head)
```